# Fastest way to filter values in np array based on changing threshold

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to filter an array `arr` based on some thresholds.

```
arr = np.array([2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,1])
thresholds = np.array([4,1])
```

I want to filter `arr` based on the values in `thresholds` when the value in `arr` is greater than the threshold

My idea is to create a mask for each threshold

Expected result:

```
# [[False False False False False  True  True  True False]
#  [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False]]
```

One way to do it in Python:

```
mask = [True if x>condi else False for condi in thresholds for x in arr]
mask = np.reshape(mask,(2,9))
```

Then to get the filtered array by just `filteredarr = arr[mask[i]]` where `i` is the index of the relevant threshold

Is there a better way (performance wise) to do it in Python ? Especially that I am dealing with big arrays (len around 250000 for arr, no specific len for `thresholds` yet, but I am expecting a big array) ?

**Edit:**
The final output expected on the data is `[array([5, 5, 5]), array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5])]`

Comment: What would be the final output?

Comment: @Divakar My final output is to get the filtered arrays.

Comment: Could you write down the final output for the given data?

Comment: @Divakar edited question to show expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mask can easily be obtained using

```
mask = arr[None,:]>thresholds[:,None]
mask

# Output
# array([[False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

The idea is to blow up the dimensionality by adding an additional axis using `None` (which does the same as `np.newaxis`) and to compare then the arrays element-wise.

Once we have the mask we can filter the data using various methods where the choice strongly depends on your problem:

- Of course you can do

  ```
  res = [arr[m] for m in mask]
  # [array([5, 5, 5]), array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5])]
  ```

  in order to obtain a list with the filtered data, but it is slow in general.
- In case you have further numeric calculations I would create a `masked array` in which only the filtered data are taken into account:

  ```
  m = np.zeros_like(mask).astype(np.int)
  m[:] = arr
  res = np.ma.masked_where(~mask,m)
  ```

  Each line corresponds now to the filtered data according to the corresponding threshold.
  Masked arrays allow you to continue working with many functions like `mean` or `std`

  ```
  res.mean(axis=1)
  # masked_array(data = [5.0 3.125],
  #             mask = [False False],
  #       fill_value = 1e+20)

  res.mean(axis=1).compressed()
  # array([ 5.   ,  3.125])
  ```

Comment: It runs definitely faster than my code. However the mask is still taking some time. Is there any more further optimization that you would suggest ?

Comment: @belas : For further optimization we require more informations about what you want to do with the result. The problem is the following. `numpy` is very fast but almost never changes the length of arrays, so there is hardly a pure `Numpythonic` solution for your problem. On the other hand, list comprehension can easily do what you want but it is slow in general. If we know what you want to do with the result, we could try to circumvent the variable length issue and solve the problem.

Comment: I have multiple select queries on one numpy array where the thresholds in the where-clause change for each query. I am trying to avoid looping and querying by saving the results of the queries in the most optimized way. I wanted to directly loop on the obtained results.

Comment: @belas : Let's assume you have your expected output ... what do you do then? Show  us that code .. otherwise we can't help you